# Does deleting superclass call destructor of it's fields?

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
template<class T>
class List<T> {
    class Node{
        T data;
        Node * next;
        ...
    };
    Node * head;
    ...
    ~List() {/*iterating through all nodes and deleting them*/}
    ...
};

template<class T>
class Tree<T> {
    class Node {
        Node * next;
        ...
        T key;
        List<int> internal_list;
    };
    destroy_node(Node * x) { delete x; }
};
```

Does `destroy_node(Node * x)` call the destructor of the `List<T>` class or do I need to call it explicitly?

Comment: It's a bit confusing because you have Node as a nested class twice.. deleting a Tree::Node will call the destructor of Tree::Node::internal_list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

A class's destructor always calls all sub-objects' destructors, in the reverse order of construction.

It does not matter whether they are virtual base-classes, normal base-classes or member sub-objects for the above to hold.

(`virtual` base-classes are always constructed and destructed directly by the most-derived-class, never by a base-class.
And if you destroy an object through a pointer neither of most-derive type, nor possessing a `virtual` dtor, all bets are off anyway.)

Comment: Hm.. how about telling a tiny little bit more about virtuals, because someone may misunderstand that "always" and think that `delete foo` will magically do everything. I mean, nonvirtual destructors may omit some things if not handled properly, so that's not 100% "always", say, like, 99.5% :)

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: Added two sentences to address those additional issues.

Answer (score 0):

When a class is destructed, the destructors of all its non-pointer members are called automatically. For any members that are pointers to objects dynamically allocated with `new`/`new[]`, or memory blocks dynamically allocated with a memory function, you have to free them yourself using `delete`/`delete[]` or appropriate memory function, respectively.

So yes, in this example, destroying a `Node` instance will destruct its `internal_list` member automatically.

Comment: The destructor calls the destructor of all submembers whether it is a custom one or not.

Comment: It's incorrect to say that a class's members are "auto" or not.

Comment: continuing after NeilKirk, problems with releasing things like pointers boils down to the question whether the member's type is `Foo*` or `smartptr<Foo>`, but in both cases the destructor of the type is called. It's just that the destructor of primitive `Foo*` does nothing. So saying 'auto members (not allocated by new)' does ont seem correct to me. `Foo*` is still destructed. However, the pointed memory block is not freed.

Comment: If I say `new Node`, is `internal_list` considered allocated by new or not? If I were you I would reword or remove that part of your answer.

Comment: @NeilKirk: No, it is not. `internal_list` is not a pointer being allocated with `new List<int>`, that is why you do not need to `delete internal_list` when you `delete` a `Node`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Never confuse pointer with pointee. You do not allocate a pointer with new (at least in general), you allocate an object of type `T` and get back a pointer to it.